# How to connect container to folder in server

Tags: pandas, docker

I m running a jupyter container on distant server with this command                                    `docker run -p 8888:8888 jupyter/scipy-notebook:33add21fab64.`

I wanted that my new notebook created can access to my repository `rep1` in the server.

my rep1 is under ~ and let's notice that when i did  `os.getcwd()`
in my new notebook i got  `'/home/jovyan/'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use docker volume mount for this, read about it [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

As for the above example, use the below command to run the docker.

`docker run -p 8888:8888 -v /path/to/your/repo:/home/joyvan/your_repo ...`

This will mount your repo folder on the `/home/jovyan/your_repo/` folder inside the docker.

Comment: i did something docker run -p 8888:8888 rep1:jupyter/scipy-notebook:33add21fab4 am gotting error **invaid reference format**

Comment: Replace the ... with your image. Use this command, `docker run -p 8888:8888 -v /path/to/your/repo:/home/joyvan/your_repo jupyter/scipy-notebook:33add21fab4`

Comment: i did it but my rep1 is still not under work.